# Syntax error in javascript usign Rhino: SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I have a `SyntaxError: missing } after property list` using Rhino with the following script which does not compile:

```
importClass(org.scripthelper.js.samples.ScriptTag)
script11Class = new JavaAdapter(org.scripthelper.js.samples.ScriptTag, {
     init: function(ctx) {
       context = ctx;
    }
function externalPressed() {
   return 1;
}
});
```

The error is on the `externalPressed` function declaration line.

But if I change my code by:

```
importClass(org.scripthelper.js.samples.ScriptTag)
script11Class = new JavaAdapter(org.scripthelper.js.samples.ScriptTag, {
     init: function(ctx) {
       context = ctx;
    },
externalPressed: function() {
   return 1;
}
});
```

It works correctly.

What did I do wrong? I'm sure that the first case is not valid Javascript, but I dont see why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because There's not a valid constructor. Also, what the compiler will interpret in the following lines.

```
{
     init: function(ctx) {
       context = ctx;
    }
function externalPressed() {
   return 1;
}
```

Clearly, It shows two blocks.

Comment: Ah you are right, I did not see it because of the many parenthesis!